# GraphQL API Hosted on AWS Lambda Function URL won't load when served over Cloudfront

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, amazon-cloudfront

I've created a GraphQL API available [here](https://au5u4btytgem5kqqs4p6j325mq0yigcb.lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws/graphql) which is hosted via AWS Lambda using a Function URL.  Everything works.  I want to host this on a subdomain on my personal website using Cloudfront, like `graphql.website.com`.  I currently host a REST API with another Lambda Function URL in a different subdomain using roughly the same methodology, so I'm familiar with what's needed and how to get it set up with HTTPS, Route 53 etc.

I've created a Cloudfront Distribution [here](https://d3jfnr6hstw717.cloudfront.net) for this GraphQL API, linked the Lambda Function URL as a Custom Origin, and set up the alternate domain name that I want.  I also created a Route53 Alias record to route traffic on the subdomain I want to that specific Cloudfront Distribution. But when I hit the Cloudfront Distribution (either the actual endpoint or the alias I made for it), I get an error that the page can't be found.  I've messed around with adding an Origin Path like `/graphql`, but nothing fixes it.

[image]

The REST API that I created which is working with the same methodology has a static `index.html` page to serve the base endpoint, so maybe that's why that one works but this GraphQL one doesn't ?

Below is the Python Application code for the `main.py` file.

```
import typing

from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse, FileResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from mangum import Mangum

import strawberry
from strawberry.asgi import GraphQL

from utils.schema import *

graphql_app = GraphQL(schema)

app = FastAPI()
handler = Mangum(app)

app.add_route("/graphql", graphql_app)
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="favicon.ico")

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return RedirectResponse("/graphql")
```

I don't have any special Auth or headers or anything going on, it's completely open. I guess I'm just expecting to be able to hit that Cloudfront Distribution endpoint and see my GraphQL API just like how it is on the Lambda Function URL, but I can't figure out why it's not loading.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't think a solution w/ cloudfront here is possible, nor does it make much sense for graphql anyways because cloudfront can't actually cache these queries (to my knowledge).

an alternative solution i implemented to serve the lambda function over a custom subdomain was to use an application load balancer which pointed to a target group associated with the lambda function.  i then created a route53 alias record to forward `graphql.website.com` requests to the load balancer url which provided the functionality i was looking for.